# Play ffmpeg encrypted video file in js

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg

I have encrypted a video file using `ffmpeg` by this command:

```
fmpeg -i sample.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb -encryption_kid a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8 sample.mp4
```

Now I just want to play the video on a local website. Is there any way to play this encrypted video using javascript?
Of course, there is not any streaming(HLS or anything else) approach, and playing the encrypted mp4 file in the browser is my goal.

I also tried shakaplayer clearKey configuration as below but encountered the 6001 error:

```
player.configure({
  drm: {
    clearKeys: {
      // 'key-id-in-hex': 'key-in-hex',
      'a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8': '76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb'
    }
  }
});
```